# tinyMCEPopup is not working in v4.2.6

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

We are upgrading tinyMCE from v3.5 to v4.2.6 and in previous we used tinyMCEPopup in many places for the requirement. But in new version it raising an error as "ReferenceError: tinyMCEPopup is not defined".

Please suggest me on this.

Please find the below sample custom plugin's js file where we used tinyMCEPopup.

```
tinyMCEPopup.requireLangPack();
var ImagepopupDialog = {
    init : function() {     
    },
    insert : function(text) {       
        tinyMCEPopup.editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, text);
        tinyMCEPopup.close();
    }
};
tinyMCEPopup.onInit.add(ImagepopupDialog.init, ImagepopupDialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Tinymce 4 popups are working differently than with Tinymce 3.
Now, you need to call the *editor.windowmanager* to open up a popup.
The code would be something like this:

```
                    win = editor.windowManager.open({
                        title: "Special character",
                        spacing: 10,
                        padding: 10,
                        items: [
                            charMapPanel,
                            {
                                type: 'label',
                                name: 'preview',
                                text: ' ',
                                style: 'font-size: 40px; text-align: center',
                                border: 1,
                                minWidth: 100,
                                minHeight: 80
                            },
                            {
                                type: 'label',
                                name: 'previewTitle',
                                text: ' ',
                                style: 'text-align: center',
                                border: 1,
                                minWidth: 140,
                                minHeight: 80
                            }
                        ],
                        buttons: [
                            {text: "Close", onclick: function() {
                                win.close();
                            }}
                        ]
                    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I used the same way how you mentioned above for windows but we are working with some custom plugin in which we used the code some this like below. 

tinyMCEPopup.requireLangPack();
var ImagepopupDialog = {
 init : function() {  
 },
 insert : function(text) {  
  tinyMCEPopup.editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, text);
  tinyMCEPopup.close();
 }
};
tinyMCEPopup.onInit.add(ImagepopupDialog.init, ImagepopupDialog);

Comment: i suggest you have a look at the plugins that ship with tinymce to find out what you will need to adapt to make it work